# How do I see only new commits between refs in GitHub?

Tags: github

In git I can easily see the new commits between references like this:

```bash
git log SHA1..SHA2
```

In GitHub I can easily see a git log output with https://github.com/org/repo/commits/SHA1

How can I see the same log from the above `git` command in a GitHub webpage? (For the record, https://github.com/org/repo/commits/SHA1..SHA2 does not work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the exact equivalent of `SHA1..SHA2`, but `SHA1...SHA2` (shows commits reachable by either of the two references, but not both of them); see the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/committing-changes-to-your-project/viewing-and-comparing-commits/comparing-commits).

For example: https://github.com/golang/go/compare/go1.21.1...go1.21.2

The references can be anything "commit-ish": commit SHAs, tags, branch names...

For the definition of `..` and `...` for `git` on the command line, see the [`git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_description).

For GitHub, this doesn't seem to be documented, but `..` shows a diff, and `...` shows commits and file diffs in separate tabs.

Comment: The `/compare/SHA1...SHA2` (triple dot) endpoint in GitHub is actually producing, for my use case, the same output as `git log SHA1..SHA2` (double dot) and _not_ the output I see for `git log SHA1...SHA2` (triple dot). Maybe this is because SHA1 is mostly a base of SHA2? but my `git log` outputs for each _are_ different.

Comment: Also `/compare/SHA1..SHA2` (dobule dot) on GitHub produces nonsense for me. Regardless of the weirdness, `/compare/SHA1...SHA2` _is_ giving me exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: @derpedy-doo Huh, you're right, `..` shows just a diff for me, and `...` shows commits and diffs in separate tabs. I've amended that, but I don't see documentation for it.